# Nested XML file validation

Tags: xml, oracle, xml-validation

I have a xml data source that have multiple xml's nested. We will load this xml to our oracle 11 g database, using informatica fro etl process. What is the best way to validate TRT against the SRC. We are not loading XML data into stage, so for comparison SRC is XML and trgt is oracle table.

Comment: I'm confused, you want to see if XML loaded into a clob(?) is valid XML?

Comment: All i want to validate is that xml data that is inserted in oracle table ( i can qry in target as it is oracle DB) but source is just XML files, so i can't qry there. What is the best way to compare the two.

Comment: so you want to compare the contents of a file with the contents in oracle?  how is the data stored in oracle?

Comment: Data is stored as txt and numbers in oracle tables